# Retrieve an image from my database sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I store images type TEXT which contains the URL of this image in my SQLite database, I want to get in my application in android these images and then display it on buttons
i just want to know how can i do it, some suggestion please

Answer (score 1):

Since you fist need to download the images, I suggest you google for something like "android load images" or "android download images". You will find many good tutorials and libraries.

Comment: No, These images are saved in my pc

Comment: Well you can not just load images from a PC to the phone during runtime. You either need to pack them into the app, or you load them from a server.

Comment: mmmm, hoow can i pack them into the app !!

Comment: You should read the android documentation! Especially the part about resources http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: I pack them into the app that's mean in the res folder  !!

Comment: what about this method :
public String getImage(int id)//afficher une image
    {

     database = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase(); // open database to perform some operation 
     Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_ADRESS_IMAGE + "FROM "
     + TABLE_IMAGE + "WHERE id_image IN (SELECT " + COL_IMAGE_CATEGORY + "FROM " 
       + TABLE_CATEGORY + "WHERE " + COL_ID_CATEGORY + "= '" + id +"')",null );
     
     if (cursor != null)
     cursor.moveToFirst();

     String cat=  cursor.getString(3).toString();

     cursor.close();
     database.close();
     return cat;
   
    }

Comment: What you want is not the string path to the image in drawables. You need the integer resource id. Store only the image name in the db (for `res/drawables/myImage.png` you would save `myImage`). You can then get the resource identifier with `context.getResources().getIdentifier("myImage", "drawable","com.my.package");` and set the image to the `ImageView` with `myImageView.setImageResource(myResourceId)`. More info about getting the resource id here: http://blog.vogella.com/2012/03/15/how-to-determine-the-id-in-the-r-java-file-of-a-drawable-resource-in-android/